# How to copy a formatted datatable in r to clipboard

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

This datatable has a copy button:

```
library(DT)
iris2 = head(iris, 20)
# only show the Copy and Print buttons
datatable(
  iris2,
  extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    buttons = c('copy', 'print')
  )
)
```

The copy button give me this in the clipboard (mac os x):

```
    Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width Petal.Length    Petal.Width Species
1   5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 setosa
2   4.9 3   1.4 0.2 setosa
3   4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 setosa
4   4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 setosa
5   5   3.6 1.4 0.2 setosa
6   5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4 setosa
7   4.6 3.4 1.4 0.3 setosa
8   5   3.4 1.5 0.2 setosa
9   4.4 2.9 1.4 0.2 setosa
10  4.9 3.1 1.5 0.1 setosa
11  5.4 3.7 1.5 0.2 setosa
12  4.8 3.4 1.6 0.2 setosa
13  4.8 3   1.4 0.1 setosa
14  4.3 3   1.1 0.1 setosa
15  5.8 4   1.2 0.2 setosa
16  5.7 4.4 1.5 0.4 setosa
17  5.4 3.9 1.3 0.4 setosa
18  5.1 3.5 1.4 0.3 setosa
19  5.7 3.8 1.7 0.3 setosa
20  5.1 3.8 1.5 0.3 setosa
```

But I want to copy the formatted table, like the table I get when I select, copy, paste (into word for example) using the browser/mouse. For example (but the whole table):

[image]

Comment: By this, do you mean copy the entire html table? It's unclear what you mean by, "copy the formatted table".

Comment: rtf is what I get with copy/paste using mouse/browswer

Comment: I know nothing of javascript, but hopefully this https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/excelBorder.html helps someone achieve an answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use *R-Markdown* and *Knitr* ([R-Markdown and Knitr Tutorial (Part 1)](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-markdown-and-knitr-tutorial-part-1/)) to create a table output with *xtable* package

````
---
title: "How to copy a formatted datatable in r"
date: "March 5, 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, results="asis",}

library(xtable)

iris_table <- xtable(iris)

print(iris_table, type = 'html', include.rownames = FALSE)
```
````

You get an output like this
[image]

Comment: I think "Copy" is the key word here.  This displays a table.

Comment: Not exactly, the key point here is "using the browser/mouse" – If you read the comments the user said, "what I get with copy/paste using mouse/browser ". The question was not a copy and past button. What function are you looking for?

Comment: A means of copying the data as well as the formatting, so that when the "copy" button is pressed, I can go Excel or Word and "paste", and the table in Excel or Word appears with the Bold headers, cell borders, or whatever other table formatting I specify.

Comment: Great, that seems to be a different requirement. I hope someone can answer that.

Comment: By the way, what programing language are you using? I saw that you suggested something using javaScript or HTML. Of course, there are programming languajes that can handle it easier than the libraries that R has-. You need to clarify what is exactly your requirement. Maybe you have an HTML dashboard. Is it an R Shiny dashboard? The answer that I give was to copy and paste a formated table when you are using R, but if you give more context about your problem, it may be easy to find the answer that you are looking for.